# Is it possible to buy a DNA sample with a specific mutation?

Tags: human-biology, mutations, snp

I would like to test a genotyping method (ARMS) on a specific human snp (heterozygous or homozygous ).
Unfortunally, we do not have any dna samples with the mutation.
Is it possible to buy somewhere a dna sample with the mutation ? 
Otherwise, can you redirect me to other solution like directed mutagenesis?

Thanks

Comment: There are many companies selling synthesized DNA, most often in the form of short oligo's. But longer pieces are also possible. What exactly do you mean when you say 'DNA sample' though?

Comment: I mean no patient with the mutation. I need a DNA with the mutation to test if my genotyping method works